# changing jQuery UI Autocomplete Results Box Style

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I'm new to jQuery and I'm trying to figure out how to change a style. I have a text box that, when typed into, sends an AJAX API request to my server with the characters typed in the box -- I return a list of all the matching cities in the world that have the character substring, and the list is displayed. Here's what the text box looks like without the list: 
[image: how the text box looks without anything selected or entered]

and, currently, how the list displays (I entered the characters 'santa '):
[image: how the list shows up now]

and how I would like the list to display (after tweaking HTML on the live page): 
[image: how I want the list to show up]

The HTML that I tweaked to get the page to look like this was
from:

```
<ul class="ui-autocomplete ui-menu ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" role="listbox" aria-activedescendant="ui-active-menuitem" style="z-index: 1; top: 0px; left: 0px; display: none;">...</ul>
```

to:

```
<ul class="ui-autocomplete ui-menu ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" role="listbox" aria-activedescendant="ui-active-menuitem" style="z-index: 1; top: 30px; left: 100px; display: none;">...</ul>
```

I'm struggling to use the HTML styles tag correctly, mostly because I'm struggling to select the correct element. I tried these two style selectors to no success:

```
<style>
<!--- other styles defined above ---!>
    .cities_list {
        z-index: 1;
        top: 30px;
        left: 100px;
    }
    ul.ui-autocomplete.ui-menu.ui-widget.ui-widget-content.ui-corner-all {
        top: 30px;
        left: 100px;
        z-index: 1;
    }
</style>
```

What am I not understanding in terms of selection? Thanks for your help!

Comment: You could use [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) or similar and try to edit the css rules related to the position of the form.

Comment: Try to apply your style to ui.ui-autocomplete
And if you can't be able to modify, top and left are defined in ui-menu, so you must mark it as !importante to override ui-menu definition, like this: ui.ui-autocomplete { top: 30px !importante; ...... }

Comment: or you can style `.ui-menu`

Comment: applying style to.ui-menu class will change elements that are not related with autocomplete, like menus, it's better to change directly autocomplete class.

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery ui-autocomplete can reset it's dropdown position each time the autocomplete event gets triggered overriding your css.

You can set an offset each time the open function gets triggered:

```
$('.ui-autocomplete').css('top', $("ul.ui-autocomplete").cssUnit('top')[0] + 30);
$('.ui-autocomplete').css('left', $("ul.ui-autocomplete").cssUnit('left')[0] + 100);
```

See fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/t7xo8qvs/